# initializing char array in a function and returning it causes wrong outputs in main

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
char* func()
{
  const int size = 24;
  char bin[size];
  char *temp;
  for(int i=0; i<23; i++)
    bin[i] = '1';
  bin[23] = '\0';
  temp = bin;
  return temp;
}

int main()
{
  char *s;
  s = func();
  cout << s << endl; //prints out weird values

  return 0;
}
```

When compiled and ran, it print random values. In the function func, I initialized a char array and tried to return it. Upon returning it and printing it in main, it prints out weird values. What is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
char bin[size];
```

allocate memory on the stack, you cannot refer to that location after the function returns:  "char *s" is assigned a value that refer to an invalid memory location.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use pointers to freed space, like the stack of a function which has finished executing.
This **Undefined Behavior** means anything goes, even the proverbial demons flying out of your nose.

Your choices:

- Use a caller-allocated buffer.
- Use a static buffer (beware reentrancy problems and multithreading woes).
- Use dynamic allocation (`new`, `new[]`, `malloc()` and friends).
- return a struct (standard container or otherwise) containing the data. Might use dynamic allocation. (Last point courtesy of Matt McNabb).

Comment: - return a struct (standard container or otherwise) containing the data

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Well yes, that works too....